# Openpyxl: write cells with different format

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am writing an excel sheet. I want to write the header (with the names of the columns) and the data (float numbers with 2 decimal digits) with the same script.

To do this I am using this piece of code:

```
    # Write the header
    for i in xrange(len(header)):
        sheet.cell(row=1,column=i+1).value = header[i]

    # Write the data
    for i in xrange(len(data)):
        sheet.cell(row=2,column=i+1).style.number_format.format_code = '0.00E+00' 
        sheet.cell(row=2,column=i+1).value = float(data[i])

    book.save(os.path.join(folder,'excelReport.xlsx'))
```

This gives me en exception:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format_code'
```

I am not 100% sure of what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: try to print `sheet.cell(row=2,column=i+1).style.number_format` is it a a string? i'm not familiar with `Openpyxl` but you are trying to set an object `format_code` which doesn't exists since you'r previous object is a string.

Comment: I will try, but as far as I understand it, `sheet.cell(row=2,column=i+1)` is nothing...I mean, it is just an empty cell waiting for content, because previously I have createed the sheet by `sheet = book.create_sheet()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the number format for the cell:

`sheet.cell(row=2,column=i+1).number_format = '0.00E+00'`

You can also probably avoid using `xrange` for the loops. `enumerate(sequence, start)` is better when you really need to address individual cells. But, if you are simply working with sequences you can simply append them. You're code can probably be refactored to look something like the following.

## Write the header

```
sheet.append(header)

# Write the data
for row in data:
    sheet.append([float(v) for v in row])
for cell in sheet.iter_rows(row=2):
    cell.number_format = '0.00E+00'
```